# Pymongo and Pyramid configure

Tags: python, pyramid, pymongo

I'm trying to configure me pyramid app like

[https://github.com/niallo/pyramid_mongodb/blob/master/pyramid_mongodb/paster_templates/pyramid_mongodb/+package+/**init**.py_tmpl](https://github.com/niallo/pyramid_mongodb/blob/master/pyramid_mongodb/paster_templates/pyramid_mongodb/+package+/__init__.py_tmpl)

but at `config.registry.settings['mongodb_conn'] = conn` get an error:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pymongo-2.0.1-py2.6-linux-i686.egg/pymongo/database.py", line 682, in __call__
    "failing because no such method exists." % self.__name)
TypeError: 'Database' object is not callable. If you meant to call the '__html__' method on a 'Connection' object it is failing because no such method exists.
```

what's wrong?

Comment: I think it's the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7201969/how-to-integrate-pyramid-1-1-and-mongo-db-as-few-lines-as-possible.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a bug in pyramid_debugtoolbar <= 0.9.  Upgrade to 0.9.1 or disable the debug toolbar.

Comment: seems like the bug exists also in 0.9.1 and 0.9.2

Answer (score 1):

if you're still interested about pymongo and pyramid, I'd recommend you using my `pyramid_mongo` package.

You can find it here:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=display&name=pyramid_mongo&version=0.1

And the documentation here:

http://packages.python.org/pyramid_mongo/

It's a bit more than just a scaffold. Unlike pyramid_mongodb, it tries to mimick the zodb package and probably some more cool things like traversal support. I never find a lot of time to do it. But it's coming out one day. At the moment, it's enough to use mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

Check your MongoDB URI it should be in format like described here

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Connections

mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,host2[:port2],...[,hostN[:portN]]][/[database][?options]]

Comment: mongodb://localhost
    db_uri = settings['mongodb.url']
    conn = pymongo.Connection(db_uri)
    config.registry.settings['mongodb_conn'] = conn
    
    also dont work

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using a workaround found here: 
https://groups.google.com/group/pylons-discuss/browse_thread/thread/394fb7ae9838f840/5d7a24a1d899844f?hl=fr&lnk=gst&q=html+mongodb+#5d7a24a1d899844f

In your `__init__.py`, just after the line

```
conn = pymongo.Connection(db_uri)
```

Add this:

```
conn.__html__ = lambda: "mongodb connection"
```

and this is enough to use the debug toolbar with mongodb as described in the pyramid cookbook.